# Is Graphics2D thread safe?

Tags: java, graphics

I'd like to improve the drawing performance of my code onto a `java.awt.Graphics2D` instance that I've aquired from a `BufferedImage`. (Swing and UI are not in the picture at all). I am struggling to find a clear answer if an instance of `Graphics2D` is thread safe or not, ie. can I set out N different threads drawing on the same instance or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Graphics2D` and `Graphics` are abstract classes without any state so in theory they *might* be threadsafe but that would depend on the actual implementation/subclass you get.

However, if your drawing code might result in overlaps handling multiple threads might get quite complicated (if you can order the shapes and there's no transparency involved you *might* be able to use some z-buffering). Thus I'd not bother with multithreaded rendering onto the same canvas (graphics object) which would render the question moot.

Instead I'd suggest splitting rendering into muliple discrete tasks and combining the results in the end.

Depending on what you're actually rendering I could imagine 2 basic approaches:

- split rendering into multiple tiles and combine them at the end
- if you're rendering complex shapes which are costly to generate then render them into intermediate images and then have one thread combine them by just rendering those intermediate images onto the final canvas (this might require ordering the intermediate steps)